# Editing own post as anon user

Tags: discussion, moderation

I just reviewed an edit [suggestion](https://travel.stackexchange.com/questions/60930/canadian-visa-refused-under-401a-for-misrepresentation) where the OP seems to have used a different user to edit his question.

It appeared to me that the anon user provided some relevant info to the question and something perhaps only the OP knew (like citizenship). Plus, I didn't want this person to lose their changes so I approved it, but what's the recommended review practice in this case ?

Comment: I always reject these changes (new information from a different or anonymous user), however , they always end up going through via other reviewers. It's something we need to discuss I think,

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Funny, I voted to reject the edit. There is no way to tell whether the editor is in fact the same as the original poster: neither profile is filled out, and the original poster has no other network history (the editor has participated on several other Stacks). The added information is not supplied in the comments, nor any other mechanism to establish that it is accurate and relevant (per [Help Center on editing](https://travel.stackexchange.com/help/editing)). The edit may not necessarily be helpful even if it is "helpful."

If I am mistaken and the two accounts are indeed the same, it still behooves the OP to [merge the accounts](https://travel.stackexchange.com/help/merging-accounts); having someone edit or reply to comments from two different accounts can only be confusing, and having someone vote from more than one account must surely be against policy.

Comment: You (and I) appear to be in the minority with that view. See this string of reviews for example:
http://travel.stackexchange.com/posts/60131/revisions

Comment: @CMaster that's just one example though, maybe most other reviewers reject anon changes. Do we have some stats on this somewhere ?

Comment: @blackbird57 I can dredge up several more examples from my edit review history.

Comment: @CMaster Even if the anon had simply claimed to be the original poster, I probably would have allowed it— or skipped the review. But now, I feel I'll have to look very closely at the entire edit history before I answer anything.